# How to display data from 3 tables?

Tags: sql, opencart

If it helps, I'm using Opencart shopping cart & I am after showing an extra column in the reports-products-purchased page.
  I can get it to display the quantity of items per category & also the total costs using the following code...

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT op.model ) AS quantity, SUM( op.total + op.total * op.tax /100 ) AS total  
FROM `order_product` op  
LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` ptc 
    ON ( op.product_id = ptc.product_id )  
WHERE ptc.category_id =192  
   OR ptc.category_id =177  
GROUP BY category_id
```

this will display 7 items from a certain category totalling 135.00 & 5 items from the other category totalling 105.00

> Quantity   Total
>   7             135.00
>   5             105.00

But I am after displaying the name of the category from another table called *category* so that it displays like this

> Category    Quantity Total
>   Womens     7            135.00
>   Mens          5            105.00

I have tried linking the *product_to_category* to the *category* using LEFT JOIN, but i'm only a novice at this so any help would be great ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to join on the category table and add your name.

```
SELECT c.name
    , COUNT( DISTINCT op.model ) AS quantity
    , SUM( op.total + op.total * op.tax /100 ) AS total
FROM order_product op
LEFT JOIN product_to_category ptc 
    ON op.product_id = ptc.product_id
LEFT JOIN category_description c
    on ptc.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE ptc.category_id =192
    OR ptc.category_id =177
GROUP BY ptc.category_id, c.name
```

Since you new to JOINs here is a helpful explanation of joins

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply & just reslised I made a small mistake with the last table which is called category_description with the column called 'name' for the name of the category but  there is also a table called 'category'.

Comment: @user1385110 I updated my query, you just need to join on the proper table and include the correct name field

Comment: Just noticed in mysql that it shows total 501 for Famous(category_id=177) so theres 501 items with the name Famous in the name, but the Famous category also has 3 sub categories with category_id=191,192,193 & what im trying to display is the total Famous & also the total of the other 3 sub-categories?
In fact, whilst looking at the tables, ive just noticed the category table has a column called parent_category that links category_id=191,192,193 using the parent_category=177 to the main Famous(category_id=177)
Sorry to be a pain & thx for all your help ;)

Comment: you should post another question asking for help to get the subcategory totals, also when posting it post some sample data for each table, it is easier to assist

Comment: ok thx & will do but first I'm going to use your code a mess with it to try to achieve it, but if i fail (which i probably will) i'll post with more info next time, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add the category description (whatever it's name is) to the select and the group by.  You do not need the product_id in the group by if it is not included in the select.

```
SELECT ptc.CategoryDescription, COUNT( DISTINCT op.model ) AS quantity,
       SUM( (op.total+op.total) * op.tax/100 ) AS total
FROM order_product op
LEFT JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ( op.product_id = ptc.product_id )
WHERE ptc.category_id =192
OR ptc.category_id =177
GROUP BY ptc.CategoryDesription
```

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time but i made a mistake as the category_ids of 3 of them are linked to the main category_id so ive posted another question / query but with regards to 4 table but dont know if all 4 are needed. Ive also posted the columns from within the tables ;) & thx for your help

Comment: cheers Ozzy for this but the category_description is in its own table.
Due to me not providing enough detail here & missing a column in one of the tables, I have reposted this with a title of 'how to display data from 4 tables' & with the reply I received off that, I'm getting nearer but the new post contains more info albeit a little confusing for some i bet